# Angular converting html to angular issue

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an HTML CSS theme. I convert the theme in angular all is working fine but the issue on the sidebar I notice that the drop-down menu mean when to click on the sidebar text menu need to open but it's not opening. I need to know what can issue is? I haven't install bootstrap in the project just import all CSS images etc and import CSS file in angular.json

Here is a little code of the sidebar

```
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
            aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
            <span>Components</span>
        </a>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
            <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Components:</h6>
                <a class="collapse-item" href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                <a class="collapse-item" href="cards.html">Cards</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

I already have added bootstrap, jquery, and popper.js

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/assets/css/sb-admin-22.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

],
"scripts": [
  "src/assets/js/sb-admin-22.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js",
  "src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the script that you given like for angular and bootstrap we need to have certain scripts in html

Answer (score 0):

Install bootstrap and jquery. "npm i bootstrap" for bootstrap and "npm i jquery"
for jquery then in your project look for a file called angular.json, replace the styles and scripts array as follows:

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
           ],
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
           ]
```